# How to make a source code change to AjaxControlToolkit.dll?

Tags: .net, ajax, dll

I'd like to change the source code for ModalPopupBehavior.js, inside the ajaxcontroltoolkit. Can someone walk me through this?

1. How do I extract the .js file from the dll?
2. Once the change is made, how to repackage the dll?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source code of the AjaxControlToolkit project from

[AjaxControlToolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com) page

modify the source and then rebuild the assembly in MS Visual Studio